# How to ignore jQuery.ajax error when user leaves page?

Tags: php, jquery

We have many JQuery AJAX calls on our page.

Some of them take a few seconds to finish.

We have noticed that when the user leaves the page before one of the calls has come back, the jQuery.ajax error event is executed.

While we want to catch other errors that might occur, we don't consider a user going to another page before the AJAX processing is finished to be an error, so how can we suppress this action from, in the example below, executing the alert?

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div><input id="first"/></div>
        <button id="buttonProcess">process it</button> <span id="loadingMessage" style="display:none">Calculating...</span>

        <div id="answer"></div>

        <a href="secondpage.php">second page</a>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#buttonProcess').click(function() {
            var elemLoadingMessage = $('#loadingMessage');
            elemLoadingMessage.show();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: {
                    "first": $('#first').val()
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(json) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(json);
                    var answer = htmlEncode(data['answer']);
                    $('#answer').html(answer);
                    elemLoadingMessage.hide();
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("an error occurred.");
                }
            });
        });

        function htmlEncode(html) {
            return $('<div />').text(html).html()
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

    $first = intval(filter_var($_POST['first'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $answer = $first * $first;
    $data = [];
    $data['answer'] = $answer;
    sleep(2);

    echo json_encode($data);
```

**secondpage.php**

```
This is some other page.
```

Comment: can you use [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete) to check if the Ajax request is complete, and show the error alert accordingly.